# How to create a set with pair of consecutive operations gams

Tags: gams-math

Hi I am resolving a scheduling problem and I don't know how to put a set with pair of consecutive operations of a job as it says on the images:

[image]

[image]

how could i code this in gams?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this might help:

```
Set a       "operations"     / 1, 2, 3 /
    b       "operations"     / 1, 2, 3 /
    in(a,b) "Mapping all to all" / #a.#b /
    in2(a,b) "Selection of pairs of operations" ;
    in2(a,b)$(ord(b)=ord(a)+1)=yes;

display in, in2;
```

Here are the resulting sets:

[image: GAMS display of sets]

It might be possible for you to make the code more efficient, but at least it works :) 
For more information you might want to check the GAMS documentation pages: 
[Set Definition_Multi-dimensional Sets](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_SetDefinition.html#UG_SetDefinition_Multi-dimensionalSets) and
[Dynamic sets_ Dollar Control Indexed Operations](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_DynamicSets.html#UG_DynamicSets_DollarControlIndexedOperations). (the ones I used)